# Find latest patch set for a Gerrit change using python-gerrit-api package

Tags: python, python-3.x, gerrit

URL for Documentation:

https://python-gerrit-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

How to find the latest patch set no for a particular gerrit change using this package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving the literal "current" as Revision would suffice to get the latest patch no for a particular gerrit change. Need not use any function from this package.